# Single dropdown menu, drops to right

Tags: html, css

I have some problems with a dropdown. I want that it drops to the left side, but I don't know how to do that. I've tried some stuff with margin-right and padding, but I cant find a way to fix it. Code is here:

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
}

li ul {
 display: none;
 margin-top: -11px;
}

ul li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #f00;
}

li:hover ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}


li:hover li {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

li:hover a {
 background: transparent;
 margin-left: 10px;
}

li:hover li a:hover {
 background: #000;
}

#drop-nav li ul li {
 border-top: 0px;
 margin-right: 40px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 width: 260px;
}

img.menu {
height: 39px;
width: 34px;
margin-top: 41px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="drop-nav">

  <li><a href="#"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-256.png" class="menu"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">General Inquiries</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Ask me a Question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which left side where can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

Comment: Using right: 100% would be wiser to avoid the sub-menu overlapping the parent.

Comment: well in question sub-menu is not asked and i never tested with left:100% so i dont know about it . so i will try may be helpful in future thanks